# Как найти в какой схеме таблица по её названию?

Tags: sql, impala

Я в документации вижу синтаксис отображения метаданных по таблицам, в том числе с фильтром по названию:

```
SHOW TABLES [IN database_name] [[LIKE] 'pattern']
```

Но что если я знаю имя таблицы, но не знаю в какой схеме она находится? В оракле вопрос решился бы сразу:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

Вопрос: как решить аналогичный вопрос в Impala?

Comment: Посмотри (SHOW DATABASES), доступна ли БД INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Если да - то получи список схем таблиц с нужным именем из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.

Comment: Не, к сожалению такой БД нет. Тут вот тревожные ответы по ходу какие-то есть про INFORMATION_SCHEMA. В сноуфлейке, кстать, видел такую. Здесь не факт, что вообще используется подобное.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545200/how-to-check-if-a-column-exists-in-impala-table

Comment: Ну тады получить список БД да быстренько составить пачку запросов на просмотр нужной таблицы в каждой отдельной БД.

Comment: Ну, это конечно можно счесть обходным решением (хотя у меня на работе почти тысяча БД :D Большая часть по юзерам, конечно), но всё-равно это очень не удобное решение. Мне кажется, вполне логичным ждать, что такой очевидный вопрос могли продумать за десяток лет :D

Comment: Вот уж точно вряд ли. Ибо задача явно не из распространённых.